# how to pass value through NSURL

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i was trying to pass value to a native html page from my web view application

I try

```
url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?bob=123&frank=321&tom=213",url];
```

but when i build and debugging program, application crashes showing  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”

Please help me if anyone knows how to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `UIWebView` class only supports loading of URLs using the `NSURLRequest` class. To do what you want to do, you'll need this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:
                      [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?bob=123&frank=321&tom=213",
                                                                          base]];

NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[webView loadRequest:req];
```

Comment: @Zubair Raihan If something you find on StackOverflow works for you, it's good etiquette to upvote it/mark it as correct. Good luck, and welcome to the site :)